# Can't I apply margin to element with fixed position?

Tags: html, css

I want to set fixed position to `div`. when i do it, it moves H1 up, So i try to give it a margin-bottom. However, it doesn't work. in my case, i only want to modify the `div` not the `h1` because i have many pages, so i want to modify on `div` and will work on every pages.
Thanks, any answers are appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>                 
    div{
        width:100%;
        height:70px;
        background-color: green;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        margin-bottom:70px; /*not working*/
    }
    h1{
        /*margin-top:70px;*/ 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A fixed element is not part of the normal top-down element flow like normal items are, so margin is not used.

Comment: @Dutchie432 , so how do i do to move H1 down without modify H1?

Answer (score 4):

A fixed element is not part of the normal top-down element flow like normal items are, so margin is not used. You need to add a margin to the other elements to allow spacing for fixed item.

```
h1{margin-top:140px;}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sUJqx/1/

---

An even better solution is to put the rest of the content into a wrapper and place a margin on it.

**CSS**

```
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
#wrapper{margin-top:140px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    test 123
</div>
```

JSFiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/sUJqx/3/